# Bibliography not coming in the article

Tags: bibliographies

I compiled my references into one .bib file and stored it in the same folder as my original article. But when I include bibliography it does not show up. This is what I wrote:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref,chemist,graphicx,amsmath,nicefrac,multirow,adjustbox,natbib}

\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/Vignesh/Pictures/} }

\modulolinenumbers[5]

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names} %% this is a style provided by the publishers

\bibliography{references} %% name of my file is references.bib

\end{document}
```

Comment: did you run bibtex?

Comment: yes i did run it. it was showing some errors because of missing comma, but i corrected them . Yet its not working

Comment: There are no `\cite` in your document.

Comment: nope, i did not cite any reference as of now. Is it necessary to cite all of them to show them in the main article ?

Comment: Yes, the bibliography will only be printed if there is at least one citation (or `\nocite` if you want them in the bibliography but not in the main text) If you want all your bib entries in the bibliography, try `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: i actually cited one reference but only that reference was shown in the bibliography.

Comment: Sounds like expected behaviour.

Comment: i am getting this error now [ This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: new article.aux The style file: model1a-num-names.bst I found no \citation commands---while reading file new article.aux Database file #1: references.bib (There was 1 error message)]

Comment: This means there is no citation in your file. (offtopic: better not use spaces in filenames for tex)

Comment: thanks let me work on the citations.

PS- thanks for the off topic advice as well

Comment: You're welcome. Did you try the `\nocite{*}`?

Comment: while trying \nocite i got that error.

Comment: and nope \nocite{*} is not working